# Random file from array in php

Tags: php

I've sucessfully made a php script which makes an array with files from a folder.

The problem is that I want it to randomly grab one of the files from the array. It works fine when I have manually set the number of files present in the directory, and not when I'm trying to count how large the array is. Here's what I have come up with

```
$dir = 'MemeDatabase';
$fileNames = array();
if(is_dir($dir)){
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
            $fileNames[] = $file;
        }
    }
closedir($handle);
int count($fileNames);
$fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
$rand_keys = array_rand($fileNames, $count);
echo $fileNames[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
print_r($fileNames);

} else {
    echo "<p>There is an directory read issue</p>";
}
```

Comment: What about `shuffle()` the array once first and then select the data you want

Comment: Just use `$fileName = array_rand($fileNames)` the line `int count($fileNames);` or the `array_reverse()` aren't needed.

Comment: And `$rand_keys = array_rand($fileNames, $count);` is wrong, if you only want one key returned use `$rand_keys = array_rand($fileNames, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove some of the code and just use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) which will default to picking just 1 item from the array...

```
    closedir($handle);
//     int count($fileNames);    // This is an error anyway
//     $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);    // Not needed
//     $rand_keys = array_rand($fileNames, $count);
    $fileName = $fileNames[array_rand($fileNames)];
    echo $fileName;
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I'll accept the answer after the cooldown is finished :)